# Error in mysql modules configuration for freeradius, unable to start it

Tags: mysql, mariadb, freeradius

new to IT and linux in general so apologize if my issue is not correctly formuled i'm in a rush and i need support about an error i'm getting on a debian 11 vm running freeradius-server.
I followed this tutorial to set it up : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JffiXdMFkOc

At 15:55 after configuring freeradius to use mysql i need to configure the virtual server in the mods files etc... when restarting i get an error, after a journalctl -xe i get

`/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/sql[340]: Reference "${dialect}" not found Errors reading or parsing /etc/freeradius/3.0/radiusd.conf freeradius.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE`

From what i understand it's because of the dialect thing that is not found in the /mods-enabled/sql file + the radiusd.conf not reading, that's where i'm getting lost i replicated everything from the video and it worked until now sooo, from a quick search all i found was an instances order problem but i don't think it is cause the logs people getting this issue and fixing it posts are different.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Fixed it, replaced the {dialect} by the one i use, a few modifications on the braces of the /sites-available/default file to get it properly running and it came alive.

Answer (score 0):

About my problem on line 341 of the file
/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/sql
It did not find the queries.conf file. I searched for the file using the find / -name queries.conf command and applied the changes.
problem solved.